# Select * where tag name is in junction table

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have a query that selects all the vid_id's where people are viewing a video and sorts them by most viewers. Each time someone views a video, an entry is created in scrusersonline with fields `vid_id` `username` `timestamp`.

I also have a tag_map table and a tags table. tag_map contains fields `id` `tag_id` and `vid_id` and tags contains fields `tag_id` and `name`. I would simply like to modify the query below so that all vid_id results are only displayed for a certain tag name. Thank you in advance for any expert help.

**Query that I am trying to modify. scrusersonline has fields vid_id timestamp username. It retrieves the vid_ids with most users viewing and sorts in descending order. I would like to further limit those results to a certain tag name**

```
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS scrusersonline.vid_id, COUNT(scrusersonline.id) 
AS idcount FROM scrusersonline 
    GROUP BY scrusersonline.vid_id ORDER BY idcount DESC
```

**The query below, is an example of simply selecting all vid_id's with a certain tag name but is linked with the video table. I would like to be able to change the query above so that it only shows results for a tag name**

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS video.* FROM tag_map 
               INNER JOIN tags2 ON tags2.tag_id = tag_map.tag_id
INNER JOIN video ON video.vid_id = tag_map.vid_id
    WHERE name IN (?) 
    ORDER BY video.timestamp DESC LIMIT ?, ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should give you your results:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS a.vid_id, count(a.id) as idCount
FROM scruseronline as a
INNER JOIN tag_map as b
ON b.vid_id = a.vid_id
INNER JOIN tags2 as c
ON c.tag_id = b.tag_id
AND c.name IN (?)
GROUP BY a.vid_id
ORDER BY idCount DESC
```

Oh, you may wish to remove `id` from `tag_map`, as the combination of the other fields **should** be unique, and a surrogate key there is usually never referenced.

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much for your time and assistance X-Zero! By the way id is a unique field in tag_map. I thought it would be useful to reference each connection. What do you mean by surrogate key being referenced?

Comment: `id` in `tag_map` is a _surrogate key_ - that is, an artificial (not attribute data) value used to uniquely identify a row in a table.  However, for pure/simple cross-reference tables (like `tag_map`), they're pointless - the relationship is (or should be) a unique row, and the foreign key references that make up the actual data is a perfectly acceptable key.  `id` itself will almost _never_ be referenced - the databse will be using the attribute columns, and you should be deleting by them anyways...

Comment: Yeah you are right. I do not know why I left it in. I just never critically examined it. Thanks again X-Zero, you have been really helpful and I really appreciate it.